# Gridsome + Wordpress source plugin - How to add archive routes by month and year

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, graphql, vue-router, gridsome

I have to add an archive widget to a blog based on Gridsome (Wordpress as data source). Standard feature like this one:

[image]

I fetched posts with static query:

```
query Home($page: Int) {
  allWordPressPost(page: $page) {
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      currentPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        date(format: "YYYY-MM-DD")
        id
        title
        path

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next on monthed hook, i grouped data by year and month to such output:

```
 {
  "2019": {
    "10": [
      {
        "date": "2019-10-29",
        "node": {
          "date": "2019-10-29",
          "id": "145",
          "title": "Aspernatur ipsam est omnis praesentium rerum autem",
          "path": "/2019/10/29/aspernatur-ipsam-est-omnis-praesentium-rerum-autem/"
        }
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-10-29",
        "node": {
          "date": "2019-10-29",
          "id": "121",
          "title": "Libero voluptatibus facere aspernatur",
          "path": "/2019/10/29/libero-voluptatibus-facere-aspernatur/"
        }
      }

    ],
    "09": [
      {
        "date": "2019-09-25",
        "node": {
          "date": "2019-09-25",
          "id": "1",
          "title": "Hello world!",
          "path": "/2019/09/25/hello-world/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I generated widget links structure using  and standard v-for loop syntax, but sample routes such as: "http://localhost:8080/blog/2018", "http://localhost:8080/blog/2018/19" go to the 404 page. I tried to modify gridsome.config.js by adding:

```
  templates: {
    WordPressArchive: [
      {
        path: "/blog/:year",
        component: "./src/templates/WordPressArchive.vue"
      }
    ]

  },
```

It results in error:

```
 "Error: A content type for the WordPressArchive template does not exist"
```

How can i enable archive routes in Gridsome to filter blog posts by year and year/month  ?

```
"/blog/:year",
"/blog/:year/:month"
```

Is there a possibility to  group posts by date and year directly from graphQL query, without further js manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `WordPressPost` type in your GraphQL and you are trying to use `WordPressArchive` as the template name. These need to match, either change the `typeName` in GraphQL or change the template name in `gridsome.config.js`.